# C program: why the program asks the user to enter extra index (asks to enter one more index)?

Tags: arrays, c, input, malloc, scanf

The program should ask from the user to enter a length of an array and a values to it's cells.

Why is the user required to enter 1 more number then I wrote in the condition?

```c
int main()
{
    int length, i, *p;
    
    printf("\n Please enter the length of the array: \n");
    scanf("%d", &length);   
    
    p = (int*)malloc(length*sizeof(int));
    
    printf("\n Please enter %d values: \n", length);
    
    for(i=0; i<length; i++){
            
                scanf("\n %d \n", &p[i]);
            
                if(i==0){
            
                    *(p+p[i]) = p[i];
                }else{
                    *(p+p[i]) += p[i];
                }
            
                 
    }
```

Comment: `*(p+p[i])` What is that intended to do? Why are you adding `p[i]` to `p` to form a new pointer? Also, please provide the exact run log - that is, show the exact input and result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the second scan line.

```
scanf("\n %d \n", &p[i]); /* Replace this line */
scanf("\n %d", &p[i]); /* By this one */
```